# Cross Domain session sharing in django

Tags: django, session, dns, sharing

I have two websites abc.com and xyz.com and I am logged in in abc.com.
I want the same session available in xyz.com also.
Please help me to maintain same session in two different domains using django framework.

Comment: You just can't out of the box. Cookies are domain specific, and might be used accross subdomains only.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342140/cross-domain-cookies

Comment: Thank You for the reply, But that is our requirement because we created some privates domain for our customers who have purchased our service and if that client is logged in in our website and, If he clicked on his private domain link from our website then he should also logged in in his private domain.
I tried one of the approach mentioned in below link 
https://github.com/ViktorStiskala/django-shared-session
But i did not find any solution.  
Please give us any suggesstion

Comment: and one more thing is that our main website is created in python framework and other private domains created using Perl